# Strange problem with UIBezierPath animation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, uibezierpath

I want to draw the Moon and then animate Moon's shadow. But after launching this code I can see some glitches on animation line:
[image]

GIF:
[image]

Why is this happening?

Playground code [here](https://gist.github.com/snowtema/f29ff7b238016b4a0597fb4db8bcf39e)

Update 1:
Both paths created by this function but with different angles (0 and π/2*0.6):

```
func calculateMoonPath(for angle: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {
    let center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.midX, y: view.bounds.midY)
    let radius = view.bounds.height/2
    
    let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                            radius: radius,
                            startAngle: -.pi/2,
                            endAngle: .pi/2,
                            clockwise: true)
    path.addArc(withCenter: .init(x: center.x - radius * tan(angle), y: center.y),
                radius: radius / CGFloat(cosf(Float(angle))),
                startAngle: .pi/2 - angle,
                endAngle: angle - .pi/2,
                clockwise: false
    )
    path.close()
    return path
}
```

Comment: How are you creating the two paths? If the two paths have a different number of control points or segments the result of the interpolation is undefined, as mentioned in the [CAShapeLayer.path documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cashapelayer/1521904-path)

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist updated question. But full code you can find by github link https://gist.github.com/snowtema/f29ff7b238016b4a0597fb4db8bcf39e

Comment: @RobotBender - do you want the animation to continue to a full circle? Or just from a thin wedge to a not-so-thin wedge?

Comment: @RobotBender you don't use arcs - just literally use a two point bezier.  (you'll need to understand the math well to know how to calculate the exact values of the control points - or you can easily just judge it by eye, use the link I gave)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, the code that generates arcs creates different numbers of cubic bezier curves under the covers as the arc angle changes.

That changes the number of control points in the two curves, and messes up the animation. (as David Rönnqvist says, animations are undefined if the starting and ending path have a different number of control points.)

From what I've read, a full circle requires 4 cubic bezier curves to complete.

It wouldn't be that hard to create a variant of the addArc method that always built the arc using 4 cubic bezier curves, regardless of the arc angle. That's what I would suggest.

You could probably break your arc into 4 pieces (Using 4 sequential calls to `addArc(withCenter:...)` with different start and end angles such that they combine to make your desired full arc. Each of those should be short enough arc lengths to be a single Bezier curve, so you should get the same number of control points for the beginning and ending combined curve.

If you rewrite your calculateMoonPath function like this:

```
func calculateMoonPath(for angle: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {
    let center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.midX, y: view.bounds.midY)
    let radius = view.bounds.height/2

    let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                            radius: radius,
                            startAngle: -.pi/2,
                            endAngle: .pi/2,
                            clockwise: true)
    let startAngle = .pi/2 - angle
    let endAngle = angle - .pi/2
    let delta = (endAngle - startAngle) / 4
    for index in 0...3 {
        let thisStart = startAngle + delta * CGFloat(index)
        let thisEnd = startAngle + delta * CGFloat(index + 1)
        path.addArc(withCenter: .init(x: center.x - radius * tan(angle), y: center.y),
                    radius: radius / CGFloat(cosf(Float(angle))),
                    startAngle: thisStart,
                    endAngle: thisEnd,
                    clockwise: false
        )
    }
    path.close()
    return path
}
```

That yields the following:

[image]

Comment: It remains smooth between (0 and π/2*0.49) and changing behaviour from (π/2*0.50) to onward.

Comment: I can tell you with certainty that trying to animate an arc of changing arc length will create bad animations. I would expect the fail-points to be multiples of π/2, but it sounds like you're getting failures at mulitples of π/4. Dunno why that is, but the short answer is, **Don't try to animate arcs generated with the UIBezierPath/CGPath arc methods if you change the arc length.** It won't work.

Comment: See the edit to my answer. I provided an edited version of your function that eliminates the "glitches".

Answer (score 2):

The way you do each of the two lines,

is simply, two control points!

One at each end.

That's all there is to it.  Don't try using an arc.

Here ...

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cahqdxeshd

Comment: LEGENDARY! big thanks, this is neat. Was wondering how to do these curves in the easiest possible way, that was also performant. UberAwesomeFattie!

Comment: cheers, yes that is the way to do it.